# Handoff action disappears after a period of time, need to call periodically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, ios8.1, handoff

I'm implementing Handoff in an app. In the app I've created a Handoff controller global to the entire application, so I only call `[userActivity becomeCurrent]` only once. However, the issue I am having is that the handoff icon (app icon in lock screen and in app switcher) will disappear after a period of time (~10 minutes), and only when I relaunch the app (i.e. calls `becomeCurrent` again), the handoff feature will appear.

I am not calling `invalidate` during the 10 minutes, I've verified this by setting a breakpoint.

So is it required to call `becomeCurrent` periodically? It's not written in the documentation.

*Note:* I've created a Handoff controller as opposed to implementing the protocol in the view controller because there are many view controllers  which should allow handoff to occur.

Comment: Having not worked or developed for Handoff, my best guess is that this may just be a system limitation (in that Apple purposefully cuts it off after 10 minutes).

Comment: this sounds worthy of a bug report to apple. If you decide to do so, great if you can report back here with the radar number so that any apple employees who happen to see this question can track it

Comment: I have filed a bug with Apple, they've yet to respond. But I'll be sure to report back when they do!